# Show that the set L of all lines with equation $y = mx+b$, when $m,b$ are rational numbers, is countable.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

My step is below:

define $f:\mathbb Q^2\to L$ by $f(m,b)$ be the line with equation $$y=mx+b,$$ then $f$ is surjective.
Then prove by surjection theorem.

However, I don't understand why $f$ is a surjection. Is it because $\mathbb Q^2$ is 2-dimensional and L is 1-dimensional, so it is a surjection for $f$ to map $\mathbb Q^2$ to $L$?

If this is right, can I say $f:\mathbb Q^2\to L$ is an injection?

Please help me with this question. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: It is surjective by definition. Every line of the form $y=mx+b$ is the image of the pair $(m,b)$ in the map $f$. As for your second question, no. You cannot say $f$ is an injection of $L$ into $\mathbb Q^2$ because $f$ doesn't even map $L$ into $\mathbb Q^2$. (It maps $\mathbb Q^2$ to $L$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "surjection theorem". Anyway, in order to prove that the set $L$ is countable, you have to show a bijection from a countable set, for example $\mathbb{Q}^2$, so your idea is fine.

To prove that your map is indeed a bijection:

- Is surjective by the definition of the set $L$: every element comes from a pair of rational numbers $m$ and $b$.
- Is injective. Consider two pairs $(m,b)$ and $(n,c)$ such that the lines $y=mx+b$ and $y=nx+c$ are equal. In particular they must be equal at $x=0$, so  $m0+b=n0+c$ and therefore $b=c$. And they also must agree for $x=1$ so
  $$
  m\cdot 1+b=n\cdot 1+b
  $$
  and $m=n$.
  In conclusion, $(m,b)=(n,c)$, and you are done.

Comment: Thank you Antonio. I think this logic applies to proving a set S of all polynomials with integer coefficients is countable:

define $f: Z^{n+1} --> (a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_0x^0)$ is a surjection because every polynomial in set S is from many elements from set $Z^{n+1}$. May I know if this is correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right. If you find this answer useful you can mark It as valid

Answer (score 1):

A line is a certain subset $l \subset \mathbb R^2$. The set $L$ is the set of all lines which can be written in the form
$$l = f(m,b) = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid y = mx + b\} $$
with rational parameters $m , b$.

Therefore *by definition* $f : \mathbb Q^2 \to L, (m,b) \mapsto f(m,b)$, is a surjection. You ask

> Is it because $\mathbb Q^2$ is $2$-dimensional and $L$ is $1$-dimensional?

Unfortunately this question does not make sense. $\mathbb Q^2$ is indeed a  $2$-dimensional vector space over the field $\mathbb Q$, but $L$ does not have a vector space structure, in particular it does not make sense to say that $L$ is $1$-dimensional. Perhaps you got confused by the fact that all elements of $L$ are lines which are $1$-dimensional subsets of $\mathbb R^2$. Anyway, the function  $f$ has nothing to do with that.

$f$ is a bijection. To verify injectivity, note that for each $\xi \in \mathbb  R$ the line $l = f(m,b)$ contains a unique point $\sigma(l,\xi)$ whose first coordinate is $\xi$, and by definition  $\sigma(l,\xi) = (\xi,m\xi + b)$.

Now let $f(m,b) = f(m',b')$. Then

1. $(0,b) = \sigma(f(m,b),0) = \sigma(f(m',b'),0) = (0,b')$, hence $b = b'$.
2. $(1,m +b) = \sigma(f(m,b),1) = \sigma(f(m',b'),1) = \sigma(f(m',b),1) = (1,m' + b)$. Thus $m + b = m' + b$, i.e. $m = m'$.